# How Can i mimic the Office style ribbon using MFC C++?

Tags: c++, mfc, ribbon

I want to mimic the word ribbon. But i can't find any resource that goes in depth on this subject matter or a template like the office developer tool template for MFC.

Comment: [Walkthrough: Creating a Ribbon Application By Using MFC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/walkthrough-creating-a-ribbon-application-by-using-mfc?view=vs-2019).

Answer (score 0):

The Office 2016 ribbon is not exactly available, but the [Ribbon Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/windows/win32/windowsribbon/-uiplat-windowsribbon-entry) is. [Here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32785/Windows-7-Ribbon-The-Time-Has-Come-Your-Win32-Appl) is one of my old articles about it.